# Simple Non-Linear ODE - would like to find solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, fluid-dynamics

In the modeling of the oscillation of a meniscus in a straw, the following non-linear ODE was derived.

$$y'' = 1/y - 1$$

$y$ is a dimensionless displacement that is solely a function of time.  The initial condition are $$dy/dt = 0$$ and we can choose the initial position, say $y_0 = 2$.

I know I can do the substitution $dy/dt = v$ and get $v$ as a function of $y$.  But I would like to get $y$ as a function of $t$.

Of course if we linearize the equation around $y = 1$ and use small initial displacement, we get sinusoidal oscillation.  But a full solution would be wonderful.

This seems like such a simple fundamental equation, I can believe it has not come up in other context.  I can't find any information for this equation on-line.

Thx.

Comment: Have you tried to multiply by $y'$?

Comment: @user28321: Is it $1/y - 1$ or $1/(y-1)$?

Comment: By multiplying by $y'$ and then using $y'y'' = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(y'^2)$, you can reduce it to a first order DE (WolframAlpha provides an implicit solution). But after that it becomes incredibly messy.

Comment: To clarify the equation is y'' = 1/y - 1 .......not 1/(y-1).  y = 1 is the "equilibrium position".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have multiplied by y'.  This gives (1/2)(y')^2 = ln(y/yo) - (y - yo).  I am having trouble getting y as a function of t.

Comment: BTW - I am new to this site....how do you get that nice equation format you use?

Comment: @user28321 you enclose your equation in dollar signs and use LaTeX syntax. More info can be found in an FAQ somewhere, I think.

Comment: The Maple command $sol := dsolve(diff(y(t), t, t) = 1/y(t)-1)$ produces two answers:
  $$\int ^{y \left( t \right) }\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,\ln  \left( {\it \_a
} \right) +{\it \_C1}-2\,{\it \_a}}}}{d{\it \_a}}-t-{\it \_C2}=0
 $$ and   $$\int ^{y \left( t \right) }\!-{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,\ln  \left( {\it
\_a} \right) +{\it \_C1}-2\,{\it \_a}}}}{d{\it \_a}}-t-{\it \_C2}=0.$$

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of literature on conservative nonlinear oscillators, but I haven't seen this particular oscillator receiving special treatment. It resembles undriven, undamped Duffing oscillator, but is worse... and considering that Duffing already requires elliptic functions, I would  not expect any reasonable analytic solution here. Even if you found  a solution as an enormous formula with obscure generalizations of elliptic functions, you'd probably ask for approximation next. Why not do it from the beginning?  For example, 
$$y(t)=1.394+0.751\frac{\cos(0.975 t)}{1+0.24\cos(0.975t)} \tag1$$ 
looks pretty good compared to the numerical solution of the IVP
$$y''=\frac{1}{y}-1,\quad y(0)=2,\  y'(0)=0 \tag2$$

[image: approximation]

Above, (1) is in blue, (2) is in red. Think of the simplifying assumptions in your model; chances are they introduce a larger error than this.

Here is how I found (1). The starting point is the energy conservation 
$$E=\frac12 (y')^2+y-\ln y-2+\ln 2\equiv 0 \tag3$$
Setting $y'=0$ in (3), we find the minimal value of $y$:
$$y_{\min}=-W(-2/e^2) \tag4$$
where $W$ is [Lambert W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
The time it takes for $y$ to go from maximum $y=2$ to minimum $y_{\min}$ is the half-period 
$$\frac{T}{2}=\int_{y_{\min}}^2 (2(2-y+\ln y-\ln 2))^{-1/2}\,dy$$
This I integrated numerically and obtained the angular frequency $\omega=2\pi/T=0.9749234\dots$

At first I tried to  look for the Fourier series 
$$y=a_0+a_1\cos \omega t+ a_2\cos 2\omega t+\dots$$
Here $a_0=\frac12(2+y_{\min})$, but the determination of other coefficients is tricky. [This paper](http://pagines.uab.cat/vmendez/sites/pagines.uab.cat.vmendez/files/70.pdf) describes an approximate method, but I was disappointed by its performance on this equation.

Then again, why should I look for a (trigonometric) polynomial when the equation involves a rational function? It's more natural to look for $y$ as a rational function of $\cos \omega t$. The simplest form is 
$$y=a+\frac{b\cos \omega t}{1+c\cos \omega t} \tag5$$
Equating $y(0)=2$ and $y(\pi/\omega)=y_{\min}$ yields
$$a=1+c+(1-c)\frac{y_{\min}}2,\quad b=1-c^2 -(1-c^2)\frac{y_{\min}}2\tag6$$

It remains to choose $c$. At first I tried to plug $y$ into total energy $E$ (which is supposed to be identically $0$) and equate the result to $0$ at $t=\pi/(2\omega)$, which is the quarter-period $T/4$. (We already know that $E=0$ at $t=0$ and $t=T/2$.) The result did not look good, it was worse than choosing $c=0$. Interpolation is apt to  produce a totally wrong  equation that just happens to cross the true solution at the interpolation point.

So, I decided to minimize the integral $\int_0^T E^2\,dt$ instead. Here $E$ is given by (3) into which I plugged (5)-(6). The minimum was found (numerically) at $c\approx 0.21$, which yields a good approximation:

[image: c=0.21]

This is the corresponding graph of $E$; the deviation of $E$ from $0$ measures the error in the solution. Note the vertical scale.

[image: energy]

The nearby value $c=0.24$ gave an even better-looking solution (1); this was determined just by trial and comparison with the numerical solution. But note that $c=0.21$ and corresponding $a,b,\omega$ were found without any references to the numerical solution of the ODE.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.  When yo gets large, say around 10 or so, the graph gets very "spiky" on the bottom.  I am interested in this very "non-sinusoidal" behavior.  I found that for large yo, y,min is approximately equal to exp(-yo). But I do not have an approximation for the period for large yo.  If I could get an approximation for the period then I could plug it into your equation and see what sort of thing we get for large yo.